# Display block only on a specific page

Tags: blocks

I would like to display a block only on the `[root]/dashboard` page, and I would like to do this from my custom module defining the block, not from the Drupal admin interface. How can I do this? Thanks you!

Also, where would this condition be better to be written? In `hook_block_view()` within the module or in the block template file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would go in [`hook_block_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7). You can use the `pages` property to define the list of pages the block should be shown on. e.g.

```
$blocks['recent'] = array(
  'info' => t('Recent content'),
  'pages' => 'dashboard',
  'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED
);
```

Comment: Incorrect info about `visibility`. You have to set it to `BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED`.

Comment: please, don't disappoint me!

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling to understand what it is you're saying...in what way have I 'disappointed' you?!

Comment: “visibility: (optional) Initial value for the visibility flag, which tells how to interpret the 'pages' value.”

Comment: Ahhhh sorry I didn't understand what you meant there for a minute :) you're right, the `visibility` would have defaulted to the wrong option for this, I've updated the answer to reflect that. Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 0):

In `hook_block` you can assign your block to any page.

```
 $block = array();
    if ($op == 'list') {
$block[1] = array(
            'info' => 'block info',
            'weight' => -1,
            'status' => 1,
            'region' => 'content_bottom',
            'visibility' => 1,
            'pages' => "test/*" . "\n" . "test2/*",
        );
    }
```

Where 1 is the delta of the block.

Comment: That would be for Drupal 6, I think we can infer from the OP's use of `hook_block_view()` that he's using Drupal 7